# ACTION_DOWN and UP, when push button

Tags: android, click

I create a class for detect when button is released, or clicked.

Now I need change image in ImageButton, when the button is clicked, and when is released.

The problem is here, if I push the button,  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP are activated in the same time, when release, I receive ACTION_DOWN event.

Why I receive 2 events when click and only UP when is releasd?

```
button.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        switch (event.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            {
                Log.d("log", "onTouch: push");
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonmason);
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            {
                Log.d("log", "onTouch: release");
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonmas);
            }
        }

        if( (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) && mAutoIncrement )
        {
            mAutoIncrement = false;
        }
        else if((event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)  && mAutoDecrement )
        {
            mAutoDecrement = false;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You forget to add break; after first case inside the switch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the revised code with break statement

```
button.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        switch (event.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            {
                Log.d("log", "onTouch: push");
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonmason);
            }
            break
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            {
                Log.d("log", "onTouch: release");
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonmas);
            }
        }

        if( (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) && mAutoIncrement )
        {
            mAutoIncrement = false;
        }
        else if((event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)  && mAutoDecrement )
        {
            mAutoDecrement = false;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```